# Doctrine OneTo(Many/One) relationship does not set id in cascade

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, one-to-one, symfony-3.4

I have two relations one with OTM and the other with OTO. The problem is when persisting the id of the main entity is not included in the other entity. I'll show you the code:

> ImportationRequestEntity

```
/**
     * @var OfferRequest
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\OfferRequest",mappedBy="importationRequest", cascade={"persist"})
     */
private $offerRequest;

/**
     * @var Offers[]|Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Offer",cascade={"persist"},mappedBy="importationRequest")
     */
    private $offers;
```

> OfertaEntity

```
/**
     * @var ImportationRequest
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\ImportationRequest", inversedBy="offers")
     */
    private $solicitudImportacion;
```

> OfferRequestEntity

```
/**
     * @var ImportationRequest
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\ImportationRequest",inversedBy="offerRequest")
     */
    private $importationRequest;
```

The forms are very simple just a collection type field for the offers which add new offers but when I persist the forms(in separated actions, the forms are not related) the importation request id is not saved with the entities persisted(the offer and the offerrequest are persisted with out the importation request id).

any tip? Am I loosing something?

Thanks in advance!

> EDIT

both form data_class is ImportationRequestEntity and in the controller after validation the code is just

```
em->flush()
```

Comment: hi Juan you have em->persist($form) in your code before your em->flush() ?

Comment: the form class is not an entity and doctrine only persists entities. thanks any way.